# Releases.exs doesn't seem to work properly with Elixir deploys

Tags: elixir

My goal is to use the same Docker image that gets pushed into dev throughout the SDLC. Once code gets merged, we want to build a container and push it into ECR. From there we deploy into a shared dev environment and then push it into staging and eventually production (all running ECS).  I would like a few things clarified.

1) When attempting to build the codebase against `dev`, our app doesn't seem to be able to query against `mydb2`. The error I got was that my user isn't able to access the table within `mydb2`. Otherwise, the UI loads because its able to access tables within `mydb1`. Within my ECS tasks, I export the necessary variables via environment vars. Here's the interesting part, if `config/dev.secret.exs` is present, everything works perfectly fine. I'm not sure why I need the secret file to be present?

2) You notice `config/config.exs` have a few imports. I tried removing this file and only having `config/dev.exs` and `config/releases.exs` present, but I run into the same issue above. Whatever I try, nothing seems to work w/o `dev.secret.exs` being present. Does `config/releases.exs` only work for "prod" builds?

```
export MIX_ENV=dev
mix release
```

## config/releases.exs

```
import Config

secret_key_base = System.fetch_env!("SECRET_KEY_BASE")
db_host = System.fetch_env!("db_host")
db_password = System.fetch_env!("db_password")
aws_access_key_id = System.fetch_env!("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
aws_secret_access_key = System.fetch_env!("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

config :inv, Inv.Repo,
  username: "myuser",
  password: db_password,
  database: "mydb1",
  hostname: db_host,
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10")

config :inv, Inv.Wordpress,
  username: "myuser",
  password: db_password,
  database: "mydb2",
  hostname: db_host,
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10")

config :inv, Inv.Endpoint,
  server: true,
  secret_key_base: secret_key_base
```

## config/config.exs

```
import_config "#{Mix.env()}.exs"
secrets_config_path = Path.join(__DIR__, "#{Mix.env()}.secret.exs")
```

## config/dev.exs

```
use Mix.Config

config :inv, InvWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4002],
  url: [host: "MYURL", port: 80],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json"

# Do not print debug messages in production
config :logger, level: :info
config :phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true
```

## config/dev.secret.exs

```
import Config

secret_key_base =
  System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE") ||
    raise """
    e1:nvironment variable SECRET_KEY_BASE is missing.
    You can generate one by calling: mix phx.gen.secret
    """

db_host =
  System.get_env("db_host") ||
    raise """
    environment variable db_host is missing.
    """

db_password =
  System.get_env("db_password") ||
    raise """
    environment variable db_password is missing.
    """

config :inv, Inv.Repo,
  username: "myuser",
  password: db_password,
  database: "mydb1",
  hostname: db_host,
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10")

config :inv, Inv.Wordpress,
  username: "myuser",
  password: db_password,
  database: "mydb2",
  hostname: db_host,
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10")
```

Comment: Is this somewhat related to [tag:phoenix-framework]? What version, if so?

Comment: I'll check tomorrow. sounds familiar?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?